# Unable to install pythion 3 on Mac Mojave

Tags: python, homebrew, macos-mojave

I recently upgraded my MAC to Mojave (Version: 10.14.3 (18D109)) and tried installing Python 3.7 immediately after by following the SO link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680228/switch-between-python-2-7-and-python-3-5-on-mac-os-x)

However I am unable to progress because consistently brew fails to install Python. Here is the terminal output of the same.

```
Last login: Thu Mar 14 19:50:58 on ttys003
MyMac:~ macuser$ pyenv install 3.7.2
python-build: use openssl from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.7.2.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.2/Python-3.7.2.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.7.2...
python-build: use readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.14.3 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/5l/gwy_gpdj6wvf_24z0mj5kyxwpdzls9/T/python-build.20190314202748.51576
Results logged to /var/folders/5l/gwy_gpdj6wvf_24z0mj5kyxwpdzls9/T/python-build.20190314202748.51576.log

Last 10 log lines:
  File "/private/var/folders/5l/gwy_gpdj6wvf_24z0mj5kyxwpdzls9/T/python-build.20190314202748.51576/Python-3.7.2/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
  File "/private/var/folders/5l/gwy_gpdj6wvf_24z0mj5kyxwpdzls9/T/python-build.20190314202748.51576/Python-3.7.2/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 204, in _main
    default_pip=args.default_pip,
  File "/private/var/folders/5l/gwy_gpdj6wvf_24z0mj5kyxwpdzls9/T/python-build.20190314202748.51576/Python-3.7.2/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 117, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/private/var/folders/5l/gwy_gpdj6wvf_24z0mj5kyxwpdzls9/T/python-build.20190314202748.51576/Python-3.7.2/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 27, in _run_pip
    import pip._internal
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
make: *** [install] Error 1
MyMac:~ macuser$ open /var/folders/5l/
MyMac:~ macuser$
```

I have tried

1. Fixing the xcode issue by following steps [here](https://jvzoggel.com/2018/09/27/how-to-fix-git-error-invalid-active-developer-path-after-macos-update/)
2. Restart my machine.
3. reinstalling zlib using brew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more searches I landed with the following answer that worked. At least unblocked current issue [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1219#issuecomment-428793012)

So that it can help others, here is what worked for me.

```
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" \
LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" \
PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--enable-unicode=ucs2 \
pyenv install -v 3.7.2
```